# http.get Response object - can't access json()?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm following this instructional video, [Building web apps powered by Angular 2.x using Visual Studio 2017](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103), and around **51:00** is the part I'm at and I'm hitting a problem in this source file:

https://github.com/CRANK211/vs17-ng2-dnc/blob/master/3%20-%20with-data/components/shared/account.service.ts#L18

With this function:

```
getAccountSummaries() {
  return this.http.get('api/Bank/GetAccountSummaries')
    .map(response => response.json() as AccountSummary[])
    .toPromise();
}
```

I'm getting red text in Visual Studio on `.json()` which says

> Symbol 'json' cannot be properly resolved, probably because it is located in inaccessible module

and when I try to run the application I get the exception message:

```
System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for AccountService!
```

Following the tutorial I used the same template as the instructor did but I think something must have changed since then since he has a single `app.module.ts` while my template came with four: `app.module.client.ts`, `app.module.server.ts`, and `app.module.shared.ts` and unfortunately as someone new to ASP.NET Core *and* Angular2 I have no idea why they're different or what the significance might be.

I've had success up to now by just making any changes he makes to his `app.module.ts` to my `app.module.shared.ts` which you can see here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/shared/header/header.component';
import { AccountListComponent } from './components/account/account-list/account-list.component';
import { AccountSummaryComponent } from './components/account/account-summary/account-summary.component';
import { AccountDetailComponent } from './components/account/account-detail/account-detail.component';
import { FormatAccountNumberPipe } from './components/shared/format-account-number.pipe';
import { AccountActivityComponent } from './components/account/acccount-activity/account-activity.component';
import { AccountService } from './components/shared/account.service';


export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        AccountListComponent,
        AccountDetailComponent,
        AccountSummaryComponent,
        AccountActivityComponent,
        FormatAccountNumberPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'account', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'account', component: AccountListComponent },
            { path: 'detail/:id', component: AccountDetailComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'account' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [ AccountService ]
};
```

Everything compiled fine and worked just like his until this `.json()` line unfortunately.

How do I fix it?

Comment: what is your typescript version `tsc -v` and wanna ask are you using ReSharper?

Comment: Try this: remove the providers section from the `app.module.shared.ts`; add `AccountService` to the providers section in the `app.module.client.ts`. Compile, run. OR, just add `...sharedConfig.providers` to the `providers` section in the `app.module.client.ts` and leave the service declaration in the shared module file.

Comment: @Hamed "Version 2.2.3" and yes I am using ReSharper.

Comment: @R.Richards These fixes didn't work, same error about missing provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red text you get from Visual Studio is probably because it VS cannot resolve the response object. The error should be gone when you prepend the following to your file

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

and change add the type Response to your map functions like so:

```
getAccountSummaries() {
 return this.http.get('/api/Bank/GetAccountSummaries')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json() as AccountSummary[])
    .toPromise();
}
```

The other issue you have with the missing provider, is probably because the AccountService is used in a component, and this component is part of a module, and this module does not have the AccountService defined as a Provider. So make sure that every module you have has

```
providers:[ AccountService ]
```

defined in it's configuration.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks that fixed the `.json()` issue and the provider issue. I'm getting a new error now though: `URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL: api/Bank/GetAccountSummaries`

Comment: @KyleV. You need to change your code to use the full URL when you run the get: http://localhost:port/api...

Comment: @R.Richards How can I do that in a dynamic way so I don't need to use a fixed server address?

Comment: @KyleV. That is a whole new question, and you can probably find the answer is already out in on SO.

Comment: just prepend a `/` to your url, this way it is absolute in terms of its based from the server root.

Comment: FYI to anyone who finds this question later - the problem with `.json()` went away after I either disabled ReSharper _or_ switched to the mapping technique used in this answer.